Laravel 10 - Sentencia withCount() solo con elementos mayores a cero
tengo una query para calcular cuantas candidaturas tiene segun que estado para una oferta de trabajo y funciona bien con withCount() pero hace una cosa que no me gusta.
Yo quiero que solo devuelva datos de los que tiene al menos uno, actualmente la query que tengo :
 $statusv2 = CandidatureStatus::withCount(['candidatures'=>function($q) use($id){
            $q->where('job_id',$id);
        }])
            ->get();

Funciona, pero me gustaria que no trajera aquellos estados con valor a cero

En este caso, Discarded no deberia de aparecer ya que no hay ninguno descartado para esa oferta.

puedes utilizar la cláusula having en la subconsulta. De esta manera, la consulta solo devolverá los estados que tienen una cuenta de candidaturas mayor que cero.
$statusv2 = CandidatureStatus::withCount(['candidatures'=>function($q) use($id){
    $q->where('job_id',$id);
}])
->having('candidatures_count', '>', 0)
->get();


Gracias por tu respuesta, me valió mucho, pero quise profundizar un poco y mirar los tiempos de ejecucion usando dos posibles soluciones a mi problema, abajo dejo mi respuesta

De nada amigo, me da gusto. Excelente investigación, no cabe duda que has agregado nuevo conocimiento a la comunidad

Haciendo pruebas de optimizacion veo que usando having como cometnaba @ElbuenMario consume un poco mas de tiempo.
He hecho la siguiente prueba:
        //Usando having
        $start = microtime(true);
        $profiles = ProfessionalProfile::
        withCount(['employee as amount'=>function ($q) use($id){
            $q->whereRelation('candidatures','job_id',$id);
        }])
            ->having('amount','>',0)
            ->get();
        $end = microtime(true);
        Log::debug('Con having = '.($end-$start));

        //Usando whereRelation o whereHas
        $start = microtime(true);
        $profiles = ProfessionalProfile::
        whereRelation('employee.candidatures.job','id','=',$id)
        ->withCount(['employee as amount'=>function ($q) use($id){
            $q->whereRelation('candidatures','job_id',$id);
        }])
            ->get();
        $end = microtime(true);
        Log::debug('Sin having = '.($end-$start));

Los tiempos que obtengo dejan a un claro ganador :
[2024-05-11 07:44:01] local.DEBUG: Con having = 0.015687942504883  
[2024-05-11 07:44:01] local.DEBUG: Sin having = 0.0091490745544434  

Podemos ver que usando whereRelation , que es una simplificacion de whereHas , es menor el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse
